# Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit

Tags: installation, fedora, yum

I'm trying to install wireshark on Fedora(latest version with gnome3) and I keep getting the error.

> Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...

I keep killing the offending process after finding it's pid using `ps aux | grep yum`, but the same process spawns again with a different pid.

```
root      1605  0.0  3.4  54424 26228 ?   SN   10:51   0:02 /usr/bin/python     
/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/yum/yumBackend.py get-updates none
```

How can I properly kill this process, or use yum to install wireshark properly?

Comment: What is the process?

Comment: updated with the result of ps aux | grep yum to show process

Comment: A lot of the answers here show how to prevent it from happening in general but not how to solve the problem if you're stuck in the situation currently.  I tried a suggestion in an answer from another question: to remove /var/run/yum.pid and it instantly resolved the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is PackageKit attempting to update the yum database so that it can show you a desktop icon when there are updates to apply.

It should only run for short periods - if it is failing to complete then it suggests there is some sort of problem with your yum configuration such that it is hanging trying to update the status of one of the repositories or something.

Comment: unfortunately that actually makes sense in my case, the internet here is abysmal/filtered

Comment: ok nevermind, I restarted and now I can use yum.  I feel like I'm working on Windows.

Comment: @user77017 `I feel like I'm working on Windows` - Recompile your distribution to use a package manager other than yum. Should give you that Linux feeling.

Comment: lol todda, recompiling is annoying and time consuming, I would rather the default package manager work properly with yum

Answer (score 5):

If you really don't like PackageKit, you can remove it by running the following command as root:

```
 yum remove PackageKit
```

You can also disable PackageKit from checking for updates by running gpk-prefs from the terminal:

```
 gpk-prefs &disown
```

In the preferences window, change **Check for updates** to **never**.

Answer (score 4):

Stop the daemon of packagekit with:

```
service packagekitd stop
```

I don't remember if the name is "packagekitd". I also don't remember if in the last versions of fedora PK is a daemon or only a user process.

If you want disable the process check the command "ntsysv" as root in a terminal and the autostart applications in your desktop preferences.

For your problem with the internet connection and the download of packages, check the plugin fastestmirror for yum. The configuration is very simple. Also use the presto plugin.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, at least on F15, though it might do on earlier versions. On F15 it is dbus activated, so it starts as soon as somebody (the Gnome control centre applet most likely) tries to talk to it over dbus.

Comment: You're right https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699263 .

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to correct this problem.

You can turn off the system auto update, and can resolve it.

In China, I tested it this way and it works well.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Super User! Maybe you could explain how to do this to make your answer a little more detailed? Just a thought.

Comment: To disable packagekit: in terminal run gpk-prefs and select "Check for updates: Never ".

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution to this problem.

The "PackageKit" process will only start if your computer is idle. With this in mind we should just log out of Linux and log back in. We should, then, immediately open a terminal window and run yum before the system can go idle.

That's it!